# How to make generic extension method with ref arg in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, generics, extension-methods

I am trying to remake javascript method "Shift()" to my c# library.
The method should return the first item in array and rewrite array to new with correct length.
code:

```
        public static T Shift<T>(this ref T[] array)
        {
            T item = array[0];

            if (array.Length == 1)
            {       
                 array = new T[] { };
                 return item;
            }

            T[] shiftedArray = new T[array.Length - 1];
            for (int i = 1; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                shiftedArray[i - 1] = array[i];
            }
            array = shiftedArray;

            return item;
        }
```

I want it to be extension and generic. Any ideas?

Comment: You can't do this, as the length of a .NET array is immutable and extension methods can't replace their `this` arguments if they're references. A better fit for JavaScript's array types is `List<T>`.

Comment: so can I return new shifted array and use out keyword to "returning" first item?

Comment: You could use a regular method (`T Shift<T>(ref T[] array)`) but it could not be an extension method, and invoking it would be clunky compared to JS (`value = ArrayHelpers.Shift(ref myArray)`. Of course there's also the matter of performance of using something like this as opposed to `IEnumerable` or `Queue` or `ArraySegment` to "shift", but if you're translating JS code I suppose that's less of a concern.

Comment: Ok thaks you very helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`shift` in js modifies the existing collection, so appropriate approach would be using `List<T>`. Something like:

```cs
public static T Shift<T>(this List<T> list)
{
    T item = list[0];
    
    list.RemoveAt(0);

    return item;
}
```

`this ref` has a special meaning in C# and can be used with conjunction with `struct`s. For your use case you can see it on special ones - [`Span` and `Memory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/memory-and-spans/memory-t-usage-guidelines):

```
public static T Shift<T>(this ref Memory<T> array)
{
    T item = array.Span[0];

    if (array.Length == 1)
    {       
        array = Memory<T>.Empty;
        return item;
    }
    
    array = array.Slice(1);

    return item;
}

public static T Shift<T>(this ref Span<T> array)
{
    T item = array[0];

    if (array.Length == 1)
    {       
        array = Span<T>.Empty;
        return item;
    }
    
    array = array.Slice(1);

    return item;
}
```

And usage:

```cs
Span<int> span = new [] { 1, 2, 3 };
int i1 = span.Shift();
int i2 = span.Shift();
```

But usually those are used for special high performance scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

I solve it by this but still not extension method:

```
        public static T Shift<T>(ref IEnumerable<T> collection)
        {
            T firstItem = collection.First();
            collection = collection.Skip(1);
            return firstItem;
        }
```